# Does Tekton Triggers support HTTP GET requests?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Does anyone know if Tekton event listeners and triggers work with HTTP GET requests?

Going off of this guide: https://tekton.dev/docs/getting-started/triggers/

I tried to create a binding that doesn't take any params, similar this:

```
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TriggerBinding
metadata:
  name: http-get-translater
spec:
  params:
  - name: placeholder
    value: nothing
```

But it always requires a spec with params.

The closest I got was a POST with an empty JSON, `{}`. I could not even get things working with no JSON in the data payload.

Are GET requests not possible?

Thank you for your help